# Ubuntu/vsftpd - connection closed by remote host after entering password

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, ubuntu-12.04, vsftpd

I have set up vsftpd on numerous Ubuntu boxes without any problems, but in this particular case I am having a heck of a time getting it to work for some reason.

When I attempt to connect from another computer using FTP it allows me to enter a username and password, but then immediately responds with "500 OOPS: Connection closed by remote host."

I have tried many different configuration settings and always have the same result.  Also after disabling the firewall completely.  Nothing appears in the log file other than:

Thu Jan 24 15:00:24 2013 [pid 2] CONNECT: Client "192.168.1.109"

Where 192.168.1.109 of course is the address of the computer I'm connecting from.  No actual errors to speak of.

I can't seem to find any instance of anyone having this exact problem.  Suggested solutions to other similar problems have no effect.  Can anyone offer some suggestions regarding things I might not be considering?

And any more information I should provide, just let me know.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here was the solution:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37539/vsftpd-fails-pam-authentication

Basically comment out

auth       required     pam_shells.so

in /etc/pam.d/vsftpd

Was able to track that down after tailing auth.log.  I hope there aren't serious downsides to this but at least it got me back in business today.